# Working with JavaScript module

Tags: javascript

I read [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules) and [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import), and wrote the below files:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<script type="module">
    (async () => {
      const moduleSpecifier = './lib.mjs';
      const {_default, repeat, shout} = await import(moduleSpecifier);
      repeat('hello');
      // → 'hello hello'
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = shout('Dynamic import in action');
      // → 'DYNAMIC IMPORT IN ACTION!'

    })();
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p id="demo">Loading ..</p>

</body>
</html>
```

`lib.mjs`:

```
export const repeat = (string) => `${string} ${string}`;
export function shout(string) {
  return `${string.toUpperCase()}!`;
}
```

But once trying it at chrome, I got the below:

> Access to Script at 'file:///Users/hasan/Documents/mjs/lib.mjs' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response.
>   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

In `nodejs` I can add the below line, but can I do it to my file, knowing that it is not running from server!

```
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

**UPDATE**

I tried running it from [this server](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher), and set the `CORS`, but got the below error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced
>   for module scripts per HTML spec.

**UPDATE 2**
It worked with me when I renamed the `.mjs` to `.js`, is this means the `.mjs` not yet supported!!

Comment: You need a server for serving files, it's not possible to use local files

Comment: @bambam how can I add the CORS to these files f I run them from server!

Comment: @HasanAYousef: That depends on your server.

Comment: @SLaks trying to use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Comment: You can always do something like install the Chrome CORS plugin, which lets you turn on/off CORS access checks. I've used this quite a bit when, for instance, developing my UI code in the Angular CLI (port 4200) and running a Python Flask server (port 3000), and using the UI code to access the Flask endpoints. You'll get a CORS error without configuring the backend server properly (which you really should know how to do...), but if you toggle on that CORS plugin, it all works. 

Note...DO NOT FORGET TO TOGGLE IT OFF when you're done. Many websites will collapse if you leave it on (e.g. FB).

Comment: @TimConsolazio still the same, even with: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en

Comment: You are serving from HTTP (both the web pages and the thing you are trying to access)?

Comment: @TimConsolazio yes

Comment: Notice that the `.mjs` file extension is only a node.js convention. Browsers don't care.

Comment: The server has to know the .mjs MIME type

Comment: @Kokodoko how to make it know it?

Comment: It depends on the server but google is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error output is because JavaScript modules are fetched with CORS, and I guess you did not use a server that set up the proper headers as explained in this article: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

In your second attempt with 200 OK Web Server extension for Chrome, it does not yet support JavaScript modules because of lacking MIME type support. There are an issue for this on the developers' Github https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome/issues/133